# Linux Audio Headphone Output (Jack, Pulse, Alsa) Configuration

Tags: headphones, reaper, laptop, linux

I'm currently using AV Linux on a MacBook Pro, and am using Reaper for my DAW.

I'm trying to output the sound from my DAW through the headphones output into a mixer. I currently don't have an audio interface.

I just want to hear my virtual synthesizers through the mixer or my headphones.

I'm having trouble getting sound however and I'm not sure if I should use Jack, Alsa, or Pulse. I'm not sure how the audio settings should be configured to do this.

Can anyone provide guidance?

Comment: I've never used nix, or Reaper, but isn't there just a control panel in your DAW to direct the output?

Comment: I guess what I am really asking is whether I should be using Jack, Alsa, or Pulse for outputting a vst synth from DAW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up configuring my DAW to use Jack and Alsa, with the output through HDMI.